# Swift Image Switching for full screen

Tags: swift, image

I am creating an app in Swift and have all of the screen I need already mapped out in Png files. I simply want to import each image and then when the user clicks, just switch the image. I have never used Swift before and know that this is not traditional development, but how would I approach this to begin? Is there a way that I can link the saved data from NS storage to Healthkit?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want a simple controller that has an image has background and when the user tap on the view it changes the image ? 
If this is what you want just link your imageView from the storyboard in your viewController then :

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    self.yourImageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourfirstimage.png")
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   self.yourImageView.image = UIImage(named: "yournewimage.png")
}
```